# Swift - Segmentation fault, conforming to a protocol

Tags: swift, swift2

I have a class

```
class Presenter<T: UIViewController where T: protocol<ViewInput, ViewController>>: NSObject
{
  override init()
  {
    super.init()

    Layer.sharedInstance.service.addListener(self)
  }
}
```

I want `Presenter` conform to one more `Protocol` and write an extension:

```
extension Presenter: OneMoreProtocol
{
  func doSomething()
  {
    self.update()
  }
}
```

But this trow an error: While emitting IR for source file ..../Presenter.swift (Segmentation fault)

The protocol looks:

```
@objc protocol OneMoreProtocol: AnyObject
{
  optional func doSomething()
}
```

So if I remove extension the error: `addListener` that is described above in this case throws this error:
Argument type 'Presenter' does not conform to expected type 'OneMoreProtocol'

How can I make conforming in a right way?

Answer (score 0):

Now I think I understand better the issue. The new protocol you added is marked with @objc attribute. You then have to mark the method in the extension Presenter with the @objc like this:

```
@objc func doSomething()
```

But you have a bigger problem now: "@objc is not supported within extensions of generic classes."

I am not sure what you are trying to achieve in the end but a simple trick would be a protocol extension.

```
protocol OneMoreProtocol
{
    func doSomething()
}

extension OneMoreProtocol {
    func doSomething() {}
}
```

And now you have an empty implementation for doSomething so you don't have to write an implementation everywhere where the protocol is adopted.

Comment: well I am new in Swift, I just support already created sources, I am not sure if we need AnyObject and what actually this does for us.

Comment: hm the same issue issue: Command failed due to signal: Segmentation fault: 11

Comment: seems there is only a solution to implement protocol method in the class instead of extension?

Comment: If you want an optional method, this what I can come up with (with the bit of code that you shown). If you don't want an optional method in the protocol, there is no need to use the @objc attribute when declaring the protocol.